# Why is forwarding variadic parameters invalid?

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

Consider the variadic function parameter:

```
func foo(bar:Int...) -> () { }
```

Here `foo` can accept multiple arguments, eg `foo(5,4)`. I am curious about the type of `Int...` and its supported operations. For example, why is this invalid?

```
func foo2(bar2:Int...) -> () {
    foo(bar2);
}
```

Gives a error:

> Could not find an overload for '_conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments

Why is forwarding variadic parameters invalid?

What is the "conversion" the compiler is complaining about?

Comment: You'd think that, with the focus the language authors clearly had on righting [the wrongs of C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c), that they would have made this possible.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024376/passing-an-array-to-a-function-with-variable-number-of-args-in-swift/24024428#24024428

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `foo`, the compiler expects a series of arguments, each of which must be an `Int`.

In the body of `foo2`, `bar2` summarises all the passed arguments and actually has the type `Int[]` for all practical purposes. Thus, you cannot pass it directly to `foo` — as `foo` wants `Int` arguments, and not an `Int[]`.

As for a solution to this: see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046142/how-to-forward-functions-with-variadic-parameters).

Comment: Is there anyway to turn `Int[]` into a series of arguments so that what the user is attempting to accomplish can be accomplished?

Comment: So within the body of `foo` you can essentially treat `bar` as a `Int[]`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046142/how-to-forward-functions-with-variadic-parameters. Basically, you overload `foo` with an `Int[]` argument.

Comment: @awesomeyi Yes, that's it.

Comment: Kind of defeats the convenience of variadic parameters in the first place though, doesn't it!

Comment: Yes, partially at any rate. Hopefully the language can provide a better solution in a future revision.

Comment: what if my `foo` function is actually an apple function, like for example `localizedStringWithFormat`?

Answer (score 0):

You can forward a variadic argument but the function you forward it to has to be defined with a parameter that is an array, not a variadic. So write your foo function as

```
func foo(bar:[Int]) -> () { }
```

and it works.