# Function calling same parameter own parameters(Array) Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

My question so basic.I cant call function with same array parameter as shown in the below.

```
import UIKit

var myArray = [String]() // <= This line from one class

func myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: String...) { . //This function from same class with array
    myArray = arg_myArray
}

func myArrayFunc2(arg2_myArray: String...) { //This function from another class
    myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: arg2_myArray) // <= This line gives error
}
```

My error is :
Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: Please show the complete code along with the classes which hold the methods.

Comment: Known problem: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-128

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to forward functions with variadic parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046142/how-to-forward-functions-with-variadic-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign `arg_myArray` as `myArray` because `arg_myArray` isn't array of strings but just single string.

If you need to assign new array as `myArray` replace this:

```
func myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: String...) {
    myArray = arg_myArray
}

func myArrayFunc2(arg2_myArray: String...) {
    myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: arg2_myArray)
}
```

with

```
func myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: [String]) {
    myArray = arg_myArray
}

func myArrayFunc2(arg2_myArray: [String]) {
    myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: arg2_myArray)
}
```

But if you need to just add single string to your string array you can use `myArray.append(/* string */)` to append new object (in your case string value) to array

```
func myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: String) {
    myArray.append(arg_myArray)
}

func myArrayFunc2(arg2_myArray: String) {
    myArrayFunc1(arg_myArray: arg2_myArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update this line like below.

```
var myArray: [String] = [String]()
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the question, a good answer should always explain what the problem was and how this code helps.